# Is procedures should be removed after use?

Tags: sql, batch-file, procedure

I have many procedures in my database that I execute every night (with `cron`) with a batch who runs SQL*Plus and run them.

So my question is, what is the best practice between :

1. Create, execute and drop procedures with the batch
2. Let the procedures in the database, and just execute them

Comment: If they are used regularly, then #2 - this way the cron job only needs execute permission, not ddl permission. And it is fewer moving parts - less things can go wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best practice  is to leave the stored procedures in the database and just execute them. This allows the server to cache the execution plan, but more importantly allows you to run the cron job with limited user privileges only requiring execute permissions. Your first option requires permissions to drop and edit procedures and that is generally not a good idea, especially if this a production server. A bug in this code could result in other procedures that are unrelated to this cron job being dropped.